# Changing values in a multi-dimensional array via reference (in PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference

The following PHP function finds the node in the multi-dimensional array by matching its key:

```
<?php
function & findByKey($array, $key) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if(strcasecmp($k, $key) === 0) {
            return $array[$k];
        } elseif(is_array($v) && ($find = findByKey($array[$k], $key))) {
            return $find;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


$array = [
    'key1' => [
        'key2' => [
            'key3' => [
                'key5' => 1
            ],
            'key4' => '2'
        ]
    ]
];

$result = findByKey($array, 'key3');
```

I want the function to return a reference to the node so that if I change `$result` then the original `$array` also changes (like Javascript objects).

```
<?php
array_splice($result, 0, 0, '2');

//Changes $array also since the `$result` is a reference to:
$array['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Tried using array_column ? That should be a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1) specify your `$array` parameter as a reference:

```
function & findByKey(&$array, $key) {
```

2) assign the variable `$result` by reference using the `&`:

```
$result = &findByKey($array, 'key3');
```

Since you are calling your function recursively, you need to also assign `$find` by reference as well.

altogether:

```
function & findByKey(&$array, $key) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if(strcasecmp($k, $key) === 0) {
            return $array[$k];
        } elseif(is_array($v) && ($find = &findByKey($array[$k], $key))) {
            return $find;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


$result = &findByKey($array, 'key3');
$result = 'changed';
print_r($array);
```